# Azure DevOps REST API ImportRequest - Returned Bad Request

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

---

I have a simple PowerShell Script to Invoke-RestMethod [Create ImportRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/import-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP) to import full repository from 1 Project to another. For some reason, it always returns bad request. Not sure where did I missed;

Can someone give me some pointers on this:

```
# Set variables
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$organization = "org"
$project = "proj"
$repoName = "dsta"
$sourceRepoUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/org/proj_old/_git/dsta"
$personalAccessToken = "     "
# Encode PAT for use in headers
$headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)")) }

# Create body for REST API call to create new repository
$bodyCreateRepo = @{
  name=$repoName
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Call REST API to create new repository
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0" -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Body $bodyCreateRepo

# Create body for REST API call to import repository
$bodyImportRepo = @{
  parameters=@{
    gitSource=@{
      url=$sourceRepoUrl
    }
  }
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Call REST API to import repository
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/importRequests?api-version=7.0" -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Body $bodyImportRepo -Verbose
```

The code successfully create the new Repo in new Project but import part is returning:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:41 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($organizationUrl)/$($targetProject)/_ap ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation to do what you are trying to do is terrible. I had to do this very thing a few months ago and I had to reverse engineer the API calls made by the UI to figure this out. This a 3 step process.

1. Create an empty repository that you want Git data imported into (which you have)
2. Create a temporary service connection between the source and target Git repository (which you *do not* have)
3. Submit the import request (which you partially have)

The service connection is required so it can safely store the credentials for the import. Here is how you properly construct it:

```
$serviceEndpointProjectReferences = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$serviceEndpointProjectReferences.Add(@{
        projectReference = @{
            id   = $projectObj.id
            name = $Project
        }
        name             = "temporary-script-git-import"
    }) | Out-Null

$serviceEndpointBody = @{
    name                             = "temporary-script-git-import"
    type                             = "git"
    url                              = $gitCloneUrl
    authorization                    = @{
        parameters = @{
            username = "PAT"
            password = $AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken
        }
        scheme     = "UsernamePassword"
    }
    serviceEndpointProjectReferences = $serviceEndpointProjectReferences
}

$serviceEndpointBodyJson = $serviceEndpointBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

try {
    $serviceEndpoint = Invoke-RestMethod "$apiRootUrl/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0" `
        -Method Post `
        -ContentType "application/json" `
        -Headers $authorizationHeader `
        -Body $serviceEndpointBodyJson
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Unable to create the service endpoint."
    Write-Error $_
    exit -302
}
```

When you execute the import, there are few extra parameters you will need and want to pass. First, you need to set `tfvcSource` to `null` or you will get an error. Second, you need to set the `serviceEndpointId` to the service endpoint you created. The optional (and recommended) is set the `deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone` to `true`. This will help to clean up the services connections when the import is done.

```
$importRepoBody = @{
    parameters = @{
        deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone = $true
        gitSource                              = @{
            url       = $gitCloneUrl
            overwrite = $false
        }
        tfvcSource                             = $null
        serviceEndpointId                      = $serviceEndpoint.id
    }
}

$importRepoBodyJson = $importRepoBody | ConvertTo-Json

try {
    $importRepo = Invoke-RestMethod "$apiRootUrl/git/repositories/$TargetRepository/importRequests?api-version=7.0" `
        -Method Post `
        -ContentType "application/json" `
        -Headers $authorizationHeader `
        -Body $importRepoBodyJson
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Unable to import the repository."
    Write-Error $_
    exit -303
}
```

Here is my script that will import a repository into the same organization and project as the source. It should help you put together your final solution. Keep in mind my script isn't idempotent and doesn't always clean up after itself.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $Organization,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $Project,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $SourceRepository,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $TargetRepository,

    [string]
    $AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken
)

begin {

    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken)) {
        if ($null -eq $env:ADO_PAT) {
            Write-Error "You must provide an Azure DevOps personal access token either as a pamater of the script on in the 'ADO_PAT' environment variable"
            exit -200
        }

        $AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken = $env:ADO_PAT
    }
    else {
        $env:ADO_PAT = $AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken
    }

    $gitCloneUrl = "https://$Organization@dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_git/$SourceRepository"

    $credentials = ":$AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken"
    $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credentials))
    $authorizationHeader = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }

    $apiRootUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_apis"
}

process {
    Write-Output "Fetching the ID for '$Project'..."

    try {
        $projectObj = Invoke-RestMethod "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/_apis/projects/$Project" `
            -Method Get `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -Headers $authorizationHeader
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Unable to fetch the backup repo."
        Write-Error $_
        exit -301
    }

    Write-Output "Creating empty backup repository '$TargetRepository'..."

    $repositoryBody = @{
        name    = $TargetRepository
        project = @{
            id   = $projectObj.id
            name = $Project
        }
    }

    $repositoryBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json $repositoryBody

    try {
        Invoke-RestMethod "$apiRootUrl/git/Repositories?api-version=7.0" `
            -Method Post `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -Headers $authorizationHeader `
            -Body $repositoryBodyJson | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Unable to create the backup repo."
        Write-Error $_
        exit -301
    }

    Write-Output "Creating service endpoint to import data from '$SourceRepository' into '$TargetRepository'..."

    $serviceEndpointProjectReferences = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $serviceEndpointProjectReferences.Add(@{
            projectReference = @{
                id   = $projectObj.id
                name = $Project
            }
            name             = "temporary-script-git-import"
        }) | Out-Null

    $serviceEndpointBody = @{
        name                             = "temporary-script-git-import"
        type                             = "git"
        url                              = $gitCloneUrl
        authorization                    = @{
            parameters = @{
                username = "PAT"
                password = $AzureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken
            }
            scheme     = "UsernamePassword"
        }
        serviceEndpointProjectReferences = $serviceEndpointProjectReferences
    }

    $serviceEndpointBodyJson = $serviceEndpointBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

    try {
        $serviceEndpoint = Invoke-RestMethod "$apiRootUrl/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0" `
            -Method Post `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -Headers $authorizationHeader `
            -Body $serviceEndpointBodyJson
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Unable to create the service endpoint."
        Write-Error $_
        exit -302
    }

    Write-Output "Importing the repository backup..."

    $importRepoBody = @{
        parameters = @{
            deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone = $true
            gitSource                              = @{
                url       = $gitCloneUrl
                overwrite = $false
            }
            tfvcSource                             = $null
            serviceEndpointId                      = $serviceEndpoint.id
        }
    }

    $importRepoBodyJson = $importRepoBody | ConvertTo-Json

    try {
        $importRepo = Invoke-RestMethod "$apiRootUrl/git/repositories/$TargetRepository/importRequests?api-version=7.0" `
            -Method Post `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -Headers $authorizationHeader `
            -Body $importRepoBodyJson
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Unable to import the repository."
        Write-Error $_
        exit -303
    }

    Write-Output "Waiting for import to finish..."
    Write-Output "You can view status here: $($importRepo.url)"

    $running = $true

    do {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

        $gitImportRequest = Invoke-RestMethod $importRepo.url `
            -Method Get `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -Headers $authorizationHeader

        if ($gitImportRequest.status -eq "abandoned") {
            Write-Error "Import was abandonded"
            exit -400
        }

        if ($gitImportRequest.status -eq "failed") {
            Write-Error "Import failed"
            exit -500
        }

        if ($gitImportRequest.status -eq "completed") {
            $running = $false
        }
    } while ($running)
}

end {
    Set-Location $currentLocation
    Write-Output "Finished"
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response! This is more complex than I thought. and the documentation API doesn't mentioned anywhere that we need to create service connection between them. I thought it would have been straight forward.

Thank you so much, for the pointers. I'll try them on when Im back from vacation and see if I could get it working.

Comment: No problem! I was afraid I was going to overwhelm you since, as you said, this isn't documented. Do let me know when you get back!